# Select TextView with trackball

Tags: android, trackball

I have different elements in my layout: Buttons, RadioButtons, EditText, a ListView and I have made a RelativeLayout that is clickable and starts a new intent. Everything works ok except that I can't select that element with the trackball. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to use the methods

```
setNextFocusDown(int id);
setNextFocusLeft(int id);
setNextFocusRight(int id);
setNextFocusUp(int id);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: I don't have anymore a device with trackball to test this, but I assume that detecting trackball scrolling and using the above methods would do the trick so I'll accept this as the answer.